# Diferencia entre un programa estructurado y uno orientado a objetos en PHP

Tags: php

Supongamos que tenemos el mismo programa pero uno es estructurado y otro es orientado a objetos.
1.-Es mucha la diferencia en cuestion de redimiento?
2.-Esta mal visto o mal hecho que se haga un sistema estructurado en estos tiempos?
Apenas me inicio en esto, gracias por su tiempo :D

Comment: te recomiendo leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour] tu pregunta es amplia y basada en opiniones, con gusto te apoyamos pero sobre dudas claras de programación ya que por ejemplo de que software hablamos? orientado a resolver que? con o sin frameworks?

Comment: por otro lado, no no tiene nada de malo que hagas código de forma estruturada, ya que es un paradigma como lo es la POO también; es decir distintas formas de tratar de resolver un mismo problema, el rendimiento no depende únicamente de si es POO o no pues intervienen factores como bases de datos, calidad del frontend, redimiento del propio servidor

Answer (score 0):

1. Hablar de rendimiento es bastante ambiguo, depende de el tamaño del programa que quieras realizar, si se puede realizar con relativamente pocas líneas de código ( entorno a -100 ), la estructurada es más legible y solucionable a nivel de errores que si programas orientado a objetos, además de evitar creaciones de clases y el uso de objetos, los cuales llevan normalmente, varios datos que en un programa pequeño no llegues a sacarle provecho. De lo contrario, POO es tu respuesta por su versatilidad.
2. El paradigma POO es una evolución de la programación estructurada (la cuál data del 1960) y por tanto más moderna, ello no descarta que se puede sacar provecho de la programación estructurada. Sin embargo fue ideada para programas de otra época y con otra perspectiva, hoy en día cualquier lenguaje orientado a objetos o que permita esta variante relativamente, será trabajada por programadores que conocerán POO en un 99% de los casos, así que probablemente no sea muy bien recibido, además podrá mermar la usabilidad y la escalabilidad de tu código.

Comment: POO no es una evolución del paradigma estructurado, es como su nombre lo indica otro paradigma; otra forma de hacer las cosas; además de eso el redimiento de un software no esta limitado al lenguaje o paradigma usado, interviene además el frontend, las consultas a la base de datos, el redimiento del propio servidor

Comment: Discrepo, el paradigma de la programación orientada a objetos introduce otra forma estructurada muy parecida a la de la programación estructurada , con la diferencia del uso de los objetos y el encapsulamiento y la herencia. En cuanto al rendimiento, yo hago referencia sólo a lo que en el ámbito de la pregunta se menciona. Concuerdo contigo en que influyen un montón de cosas más, pero he limitado mi respuesta a la comparación entre ambos, únicamente. Creo que podremos estar de acuerdo en que crear objetos para no emplear todos sus datos o para cosas sencillas, es ineficiente. Saludos

Comment: de todos modos es imposible darle una respuesta concreta, desde el momento que no sabemos alcance del software ni los demás elementos, medir a un programa informático solo por su lenguaje es muy arriesgado, convendría en todo caso que muestre de que programa se trata y hacer benchmarking de ambos paradigmas para dar resultados concretos, hasta que eso no pase todo serán meras suposiciones @Sergio Gutiérrez

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, yo he aportado mi granito de arena siendo lo más genérico posible, debido a lo ambiguo de la pregunta, cosa que he recalcado en el punto 1, veremos si el usuario puede concretarnos más la pregunta y así poder ofrecerle una mejor respuesta